# Why is my code returning it's results in quotes?

Tags: javascript, html

My code is returning all of it's results within quotes. So it appears as if it is raw html. an example of the code running can be found here

Below is an example of how the code is actually coming out of the web page as supposed to as displaying as html.

```
<a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-28069800#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa">Iraq army 'moves to retake Tikrit'</a><p>Iraq's military says it has launched a major offensive to try to retake the northern city of Tikrit from Isis-led Sunni ...</p>
```

here is the script that is returning the results.

> google.load("feeds", "1");

```
function initialize() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int");
  feed.setNumEntries(10);
  console.log(feed),
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i+=1) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

        var line = '<a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a>' + '<p>' + entry.contentSnippet + '</p>' ;

        var div = document.createElement("li");

       var newslist

        var newslist = div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(line));





       // var div = document.createElement("li");
       // div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.contentSnippet));

        container.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Comment: I will give you a hint: `var newslist = div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(line));`. Where `document.createTextNode` creates a text node and not DOM nodes (HTML). Fast and dirty is to use `.innerHTML = line`

Comment: Amazing, thank you ever so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a text node hence `line` is coming up as text.

Maybe use `div.innerHTML=line;` or use `createElement('a')` and `createAttribute` for instead of typing out `"<a ... > ... </a>"`

Comment: Thank you for such a quick great response. I got to learn some how.

Comment: @KaranJ.S. you will get your "karma" sooner or later. btw. its called `node.setAttribute(name, value)`.